# Why doesn't my CSS selector select the correct element?

Tags: css

I have a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/joduLnhx/

In my CSS, if I use:

```
.tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #0000FF !important;
}
```

my tooltip appears blue as expected:

[image]

But if I use

```
.blue-tooltip .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #0000FF !important;
}
```

then my tooltip is no longer blue even though I have

```
<span class="blue-tooltip" v-tooltip="message">{{ message }}</span>`
```

Why doesn't the second selector work?

Comment: because the tooltip is an element generated outside and inserted in the body as fixed

Answer (score 0):

Because your .tooltip-inner isn't really inside .blue-tooltip but only absolute positioned near it

Answer (score -1):

Try this this will surey solve your problem as the tooltip div create inside body element not after tooltip.
`.tooltip .tooltip-inner{
  background: red !important;
}`
[image: Tooltip]